# How to generate in memory data/table in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-structures

working on XML, for which I will have to loop through and compare the values before or afterwords.

```
<TRANS DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="EXPRR" >
            <FIELD EXPR ="A1" NAME ="SD" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="V" NAME ="DDS" PORTTYPE ="VARIABLE"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="C" NAME ="SSS" PORTTYPE ="OUTPUT"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="SD" NAME ="SS" PORTTYPE ="VARIABLE"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="XX" NAME ="EEEE" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT"/>
</TRANS>
```

I would like to put this in the temp memory where I can look through the values and add a sequence.
for ex.

```
seq key value

1 A1 SD
2 V DDS
3 C SSS
4 SD SSS
5 XX EEEE
```

Once I have this I will have to compare if value exists in the below rows.
For example SD exists in below row. so on.

Is there any data structure I can use to perform this operation in Python 3 ?.

Answer (score 1):

ONE WAY:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse('<your xml file path here>')
xml_data = tree.getroot()
# here you can change the encoding type to be able to set it to the one you need
xmlstr = ET.tostring(xml_data, encoding='utf-8', method='xml')

data_dict = dict(xmltodict.parse(xmlstr))
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict['TRANS']['FIELD']).drop('@PORTTYPE', 1)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  @EXPR @NAME
0    A1    SD
1     V   DDS
2     C   SSS
3    SD    SS
4    XX  EEEE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `collections.defaultdict` to collate your data before creating a dataframe :

```
data = """<TRANS DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="EXPRR" >
            <FIELD EXPR ="A1" NAME ="SD" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="V" NAME ="DDS" PORTTYPE ="VARIABLE"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="C" NAME ="SSS" PORTTYPE ="OUTPUT"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="SD" NAME ="SS" PORTTYPE ="VARIABLE"/>
            <FIELD EXPR ="XX" NAME ="EEEE" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT"/>
          </TRANS> 
       """
```

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(data)

```
from collections import defaultdict


collection = defaultdict(list)

for child in root:
    collection['key'].append(child.attrib['EXPR'])
    collection['value'].append(child.attrib['NAME'])

pd.DataFrame(collection).rename_axis('seq')
 
    key value
seq          
0    A1    SD
1     V   DDS
2     C   SSS
3    SD    SS
4    XX  EEEE
```